# Listar em cada cargo, os funcionários que mais tiveram mudança de cargo

Tags: sql, select

Boa noite pessoal.

Tenho um probleminha que tô tentando resolver há um tempo e vim perguntar aqui.

É o seguinte:
Tenho três entidades importantes para essa solução:
Para facilitar, vou botar apenas os campos "mínimos".

- Funcionario (cod_func, nome, cod_cargo)
- Cargo (cod_cargo, descricao)
- Historico (cod_cargo, cod_func, dataInicio, dataFim)

O meu sistema é o seguinte. Os funcionários sempre enfrentam mudança de cargo. E quando ocorre essa mudança, os cargos são armazenados em uma tabela de histórico com o cargo, o funcionário e a data.

Ou seja, tem um relacionamento em que um funcionário tem um cargo.
Um cargo tem vários funcionários.

A tabela histórica tem duas chaves estrangeiras.

Agora quero selecionar, pra cada cargo, os funcionários que MAIS tiveram mudança de cargo.

Ou seja, para cada cargo, o funcionário que mais mudou de cargo e está no cargo agora. Entende?

Tentei fazer desse jeito, mas não sei "reduzir mais".

```sql
SELECT c.descricao, f.nome, count(*) as qtd 
FROM historicos
JOIN funcionario f on f.cod_func = historicos.cod_func
JOIN cargo c on c.cod_cargo = f.cod_cargo
GROUP BY c.dsc_cargo, f.nome
```

Comment: Opa. Obrigado. Lá em cima tem os campos. Ou quer o código para criação?

Comment: Não precisa da criação não. De fato, se eu entendi bem, quanto mais entradas no histórico, mais mudanças de cargo, seria isso? Tem algum SGBD de preferência?

Comment: Isso mesmo. SQL Server. Mas me ajudando na lógica em qualquer SGBD está ótimo.

Comment: Creio também que funciona sem um BD para testar

Answer (score 1):

Creio que funcione , sem um BD para testar

```
Funcionario (cod_func, nome, cod_cargo)
Cargo (cod_cargo, descricao)
Historico (cod_cargo, cod_func, dataInicio, dataFim)
```

--historico dos funcionarios

```
select cod_cargo,cod_func,sum(*) qtd_cargos
from   historico
group by cod_cargo,cod_func
```

--"campeoes"

```
select cod_cargo,cod_func
from (select cod_cargo,cod_func,sum(*) qtd_cargos
      from   historico
      group by cod_cargo,cod_func) virtual1
where qtd_cargos = (select max(qtd_cargos)
                    from (select cod_cargo,cod_func,sum(*) qtd_cargos
                          from   historico
                          group by cod_cargo,cod_func) virtual2
                    where virtual2.cod_cargo = virtual1.cod_cargo)
```

Talvez uma solução via "analityc functions" fique mais limpa mas creio que esta vá funcionar em todo SGBD que aceite tabelas virtuais.

Answer (score 0):

Esta resposta vale para o SQL Server. Se precisar para algum outro banco, favor indicar na pergunta.

```
SELECT c.descricao, f.nome, h.qtd
FROM (
    SELECT cod_func, qtd = count(1) over (partition by cod_func)
    from historicos
    group by cod_func
    order by qtd desc
) h
JOIN funcionario f on f.cod_func = h.cod_func
JOIN cargo c on c.cod_cargo = f.cod_cargo
```

Comment: Obrigado. Mas continua sem funcionar. Do jeito que tu fez, apenas está ordenando. O que eu quero é pegar é para cada cargo o funcionário que mais teve transferência. Ou seja, se você, Cigano já passou por 5 cargos e trabalha como Gerente. Então deve ser listado assim: Gerente Cigano e assim vai, pra cada cargo. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não adianta falar isso. Qual o problema?

Comment: Tinha apertado enter sem querer. Por exemplo, você passou por 5 cargos e João passou por 4 e também é gerente. Então para o gerente deve ser mostrado você, pois você tem mais mudanças de cargo. E assim para cada cargo.

Comment: Entendi. Estou modificando a resposta.

Comment: Opa. Deu um erro. Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'h.qtd' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: A execução da subquery apenas devolve o que?

Comment: A subquery devolve a quantidade para cada jogador

Comment: Adicionei no group by de baixo group by h.qtd, mas aí ele repete os times.

Comment: @user17245 Verdade. O `GROUP BY` de baixo não precisa. Esqueci de tirar. Repare que fiz uma edição. Como fica o resultado depois disso?